# Smooth bijections $f : (0,1) \to (0,1)$ such that $f'(1) = \infty$

Tags: functions

**The question:** I'm looking for examples of smooth bijections $f : (0,1) \to (0,1)$ such that $f'(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to 1$. Ideally, $f'(x)$ should not start getting large too soon (let us say for $x < 0.9$), and then it should start increasing rapidly near $x = 1$.
Furthermore, the function should not be defined piecewise - I am looking for a simple formula.

**My example:** E.g. $f(x) = 1 - \sqrt{1-x}$.

**Context:** I am trying to plot a function which oscillates wildly as $x\to 1$, but only starts doing this very near $x=1$, so I would like to rescale the domain axis to better visualise this oscillatory behaviour. This is one of the reasons why I am looking for "simple" formulas - I need to put this formula in the axis label.

Comment: Is it necessary that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes! (I thought the condition of it being a bijection and the derivative being infinite at $x=1$ implies this?!)

Comment: @LalitTolani This $f$ is infinite at $x=1$; I need it to map $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$.

Comment: @MSDG Oops,  What about $$f(x)=\frac{2\arcsin x}{\pi}$$

Comment: @MDSG $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$ is also a possibility for a bijection.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Then we couldn't have $f'(1) = \infty$ though. In either case, $f(1-x)$ would switch between the two possibilities.

Comment: @LalitTolani That's a good one!